# Is there a way to group Rules by type?

Tags: rules, views

I would like to know if there is a way to make groups or collections of Rules so it is easier to see the types of Rules I have created. Is there a module for this? Is this something where I can/should add a taxonomy term field, assign a term to each Rule and display it in a View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "Tag" rules which is a nice feature to group / filter them.

[image: Rules tags]

Comment: Thanks David. "Settings" is always collapsed and I didn't realize it was built in.